# How to call a .NET web service from Blackberry Simulator?

Tags: web-services, blackberry, asmx, ksoap2

I have to call a .NET web service (http://192.168.1.14/CG/authentication.asmx) from the Blackberry Simulator. Already i have done it in Android with KSOAP2, but i have no idea about how to do this in Blackberry. Can i use KSOAP2 in Blackberry? If i can please give some code snippets. Also please tell if you know any other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used KSOAP2 before but I know that you can use it for Blackberry.

To call web services I use the [Sun Java Wireless Toolkit (WTK)](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/) to generate stubs from your webservice's WSDL file, which should probably be http://192.168.1.14/ CG/authentication.asmx?wsdl for you.

You can then import the files that the WTK generates into your project to call your web methods using something along the lines of:

```
//Generated stub file
Service1Soap_Stub stub = new Service1Soap_Stub();

//Web service method
result = stub.methodName(param1, param2);
```

Comment: do you know any good tutorials for generating the stubs? i downloaded the WTC but cant figure it out.

Comment: @mtmurdock - It's actually pretty straight forward once you get going, this tutorial looks okay http://www.bestcoder.net/?p=117.

Comment: Sun Java Wireless Toolkit has issue in stub generation for DOT NET webservice. They were just entity files and Web service connector was not present in it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use SAX and the standard J2ME libs.
The following link is a good tutorial on how to accomplish this:
http://www.simplified-tech.com/website/webapp.nsf/webpages/ArticlesBBWebServices

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [WSClient++](http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/wsclient/java-android-blackberry/) which generates code that is free from reflection and ideal for mobile platforms.