# Blackberry - send/receive XML data with webservice

Tags: xml, web-services, blackberry

Sample program for creating XML and send the XML data to web service and getting back the XML response from web server in blackberry?

Answer (score 1):

[kXML - XML Library for J2ME devices](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/)

[Tutorial setting up for kXML on Blackberry](http://www.craigagreen.com/index.php?/Blog/blackberry-and-net-webservice-tutorial-part-1.html)

[Google cache of page with some samples](http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:c6iimSjU_lUJ:www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/140930-blackberry-jde-ksoap-noobs.html+http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/140930-blackberry-jde-ksoap-noobs.html&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a)

If you go with kXML you need to verify the JAR file before it will work. I gave up on trying to get the kXML JAR file to work for my project and just included the source in the project.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Services APIs for J2ME, Part 1: Remote service invocation API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-jsr/)
[Web Services APIs for J2ME, Part 2: Java API for XML processing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-xmlparse/)

[How to call a .NET web service from Blackberry Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164744/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-blackberry-simulator)
[Better approach for XML Creation in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877428/better-approach-for-xml-creation-in-blackberry)
[Add XML parsing to your J2ME applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-parsexml/)