# Format data in XML

Tags: xml, blackberry

I need my data in XML format, and then sent to a web service.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720253/blackberry-send-receive-xml-data-with-webservice

Answer (score 0):

You question is very vague, this is what I would do if I need to generate XML and send it via WS.

1. [Create an XML](http://genedavis.com/library/xml/java_dom_xml_creation.jsp) using SAX, JAXP etc for Java
2. [Convert the XML file to base64binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778/how-do-you-convert-binary-data-to-strings-and-back-in-java).
3. Now, send the string via the web service.