# How to call .Net webservice in Blackberry?

Tags: web-services, blackberry

I would like to call .Net webservice from my Blackbrry application. How can I call webservice from my app and which protocol is user and which jar file i have to used to call webservice. and how to get responce from webservice in Blackberry?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164744/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-blackberry-simulator

Comment: Hello Bharath - I tried to use Java Wireless Toolkit, but it has some issues. All files generated by SJWT - They were just entity files and Web service connector was not present in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this (you probably need to setup correct request headers and cookies):

```
        connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url
                + ConnectionUtils.getConnectionString(), Connector.READ_WRITE);

        connection.setRequestProperty("ajax","true");                       
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + jsessionId);

        inputStream = connection.openInputStream();

        byte[] responseData = new byte[10000];
        int length = 0;
        StringBuffer rawResponse = new StringBuffer();
        while (-1 != (length = inputStream.read(responseData))) {
            rawResponse.append(new String(responseData, 0, length));
        }
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + responseCode);
        }

        responseString = rawResponse.toString();
```